# why spring security hasRole function does not authenticate any apis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have some trouble to make it work with `spring security hasRole`. I have 2 Role in db saved as **ROLE_ADMIN** and **ROLE_USER**. I want to give permisson some  APIs with ADMIN role, some with USER role. HERE is my code.

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
        private String usersQuery;

        @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
        private String rolesQuery;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            auth
                    .jdbcAuthentication()
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder())
                    .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
            System.out.println("configure " );
            try {
                http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/", "/*.html").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/profile/").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")

                        .antMatchers("/admin/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers("/insurance/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers("/company/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
            web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall())
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/templates/**");

        }

        @Bean
        public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
            StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        /*firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
        firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);*/
            firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedDoubleSlash(true);
            return firewall;
        }

        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
}
```

And I have `sql queries` in `application.properties`

```
spring.queries.users-query=select username, password, status from insurance.users where username=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.username, r.role from insurance.users u inner join insurance.roles r on(u.role_id=r.id) where u.username=?
```

Problem is that when I try to login, I get 403 error code.

Here is Controller.class

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String login(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email,
                            @RequestParam(value = "password") String password, HttpSession session) {
            Result result = userService.login(email, password);
            session.setAttribute("user", result.getData());

            if(result.getStatus() == 200){
                return  "redirect:/profile";
            } else {
                return "redirect:/login?error";
            }
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String profile(HttpSession httpSession, Model model) {
            if(httpSession.getAttribute("user") != null) {
                UserResponse user = (UserResponse) httpSession.getAttribute("user");
                model.addAttribute("user", user);
                return "profile";
            } else {
                return "redirect:/home";
            }
        }
```

I have tried to solve it, but could not find. If you have any advice, please tell.

I changed my config file as suggested. I added my custom login logic, now when I want to go /admins or another url, I **redirect to login url** Here is my config code

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/insurance/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/company/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login.html").permitAll().usernameParameter("username") .passwordParameter("password")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/profile.html", true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have your own login, don't. Spring Security should take care of that. You have rules, but Spring Security will never see a logged in user, as that process completly bypasses Spring Security.

Comment: @M.Deinum,can you please look at my code again.I updated as you said

Comment: Remove the `try/catch` from your config method. Also without setting up an authentication manager it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just add login also in exceptions for authentication.
Give this a try

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/insurance/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/company/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login.html").permitAll().usernameParameter("username") .passwordParameter("password")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/profile.html", true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which login do you suggest about?Sorry, I did not understand you

Comment: I was talking about .antMatchers("/login").permitALL()

Comment: basically you need to remove authentication for login API itself in order to user it to authenticate(as you are not already authenticated at that time)

Comment: I removed login part as you said, still no luck. But thank you

Comment: i asked you to add that login part in permit all

Comment: http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()

Comment: and the rest of it remains same

Comment: unfortunately, no success